# Disparity in versions of Python 2 packages and Python 2 interpreter

Tags: package-management, python

I don't quite understand the apparent disagreement in versions between the various Python 2 packages and the Python 2 interpreter on my Ubuntu 16.04 system.

Running

```
$ readlink -e $(which python python2)
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7

$ python --version && python2 --version
Python 2.7.12
Python 2.7.12
```

tells me that `python` and `python2` are symlinked to `python2.7` and the version of the Python 2 interpreter on my system is `Python 2.7.12`. So far so good, nothing surprising.

Running

```
$ dpkg -s python | grep Version
Version: 2.7.11-1
```

tells me that the version of the `python` package is `2.7.11-1`, which disagrees with the version of the Python 2 interpreter.

On the other hand, running

```
$ dpkg -s python2.7 | grep Version
Version: 2.7.12-1~16.04
```

tells me that the version of the `python2.7` package is `2.7.12`, which agrees with the version of the Python 2 interpreter.

Given that the version of the Python 2 interpreter is `2.7.12`, is the interpreter then provided by only the `python2.7` package? If so, what does the `python` package do if it doesn't provide the interpreter that the system currently uses?

Comment: Both the `python` and `python2.7` packages in the official 16.04 repositories are at version `2.7.11-1`. Do you have third-party repositories enabled?

Answer (score 4):

The interpreter `/usr/bin/python2.7` is provided by the `python2.7-minimal` package, as you can see with `apt-file search /usr/bin/python2.7`. The `python` package is what is called a *metapackage*: because the Python installation is split between several packages, the `python` package provides a simple way to install all those packages at once. If someone needs only the bare minimum, they can install only the `python2.7-minimal` package.

Answer (score 1):

By default you have a number of versions of Python installed.  If a program required a specific version, the author would call on that version by the path-name.

If you don't have the author's required version you could install that specific version.  You can still maintain your default version choice which `/usr/bin/python` symbolic linked to the the version number.  In your case, it's most likely linked to `/usr/bin/python2.7`.

You can view your installed versions with:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/bin/python*
```

My answer is mostly addressing the last part of your question, `If so, what does the python package do if it doesn't provide the interpreter that the system currently uses?`.

When you run `python` it's searching your path and finding `/usr/bin/python`, which is linked to `/usr/bin/python`.  So you're actually checking the version of `/usr/bin/python2.7`.

Also, on occasions there are **discrepancies in the version output** depending on the method checked.  As in this case, checking via the actual program and checking via the distribution packaging.  When this occurs the version stamp in the actual program would be the most likely be more precise.

Another way to verify the actual version of the python interpreter is by running it from the commandline:

```
$ python
```

Output:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 


$ python2.7
```

Output:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: @Zanna I mean packages installed by the user from the repository from using `sudo apt`.  It unlikely that a developer would would look for an installed Python in `/uer/local` or anywhere else beside `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @Zanna I just happened to be reading a year old post.  It's incredible how a person so often sees what they are expecting rather than what's there.  I'm just noticing my typo `/usr/local/bin/python*` and understand your comment differently.  I'm upvoting your comment and fixing my answer.  Thanks!  By the way, let me know if you see other discrepancies.  I'll try to be more thorough in the future.