# python version with xenial

Tags: 16.04, python

can somebody explain me this magic

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt-cache policy python
python:
  Installed: 2.7.11-1
  Candidate: 2.7.11-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.11-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
root@ubuntu:~# python --version
Python 2.7.12
root@ubuntu:~#
```

xenial repo has 2.7.11 version of ubuntu but after installing it's python 2.7.12.

Is this bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you use pip to update python ? Could you give us the result of "which python" please ?

Comment: Look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/825971/disparity-in-versions-of-python-2-packages-and-python-2-interpreter/825981#825981

Comment: Possible dupe at http://askubuntu.com/questions/825971/disparity-in-versions-of-python-2-packages-and-python-2-interpreter. Being the author of the dupe target, I am still not sure if the answers currently there really answer my question...

Comment: @edwinksl this is definitely the same question that I ask. 
I'm glad I'm not only one who is confused